# Android, Zxing: Not able to pass result into asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, zxing

I am trying to pass results from scanning into asynctask, because then I need to call php script from server. But somehow it does not work.

Asynctask should be functional, but now after some time I am not sure about anything.

But when I use this code:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(com.google.zxing.Result result) {
    Log.v("TAG", result.getText());
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

It works and logs my result.

And when I change it into this:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(com.google.zxing.Result result) {
    Log.v("MATEJ", result.getText());
    ScannerService scannerService = new ScannerService(this);
    scannerService.execute(result.getText());
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

It logs nothing and application stops working without error message.

Comment: show your `ScannerService` code

Comment: It definitely logs something, check the filters you have set in your logcat. And also you need to show us more code! Nobody can figure out what the problem is from seeing three lines of code!

Comment: _result.getText()_ returns  any kind of URL ?

Comment: Ok, thank you everybody. I was not authorized to acces my own website from IP I had on phone :D I did not implement that server side, so I did not know, because it was functional when tried on desktop. Sorry for question, solved :-)